¿porque me sale error en mi codigo?
estoy programando un sistema de ventas y me estoy guiando de un video ahora mismo esto programando lo que seria el login del Jframe y escribi el codigo tal cual como en el video pero me sale error
package Vista;

import Modelo.login;
import Modelo.LoginDAO;

public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {
login lg = new login();
LoginDAO login = new LoginDAO();
public Login() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public void valodar(){
    String correo = txtCorreo.getText();
    String pass = String.valueOf(txt_Password.getPassword());
    if (!"".equals(correo)||!"".equals(pass)) {
        lg = login.log(correo, pass);
        if (lg.getCorreo()! = null && lg.getPass() != null) {
           Sistema sis = new Sistema();
           sis.setVisible(true);
           dispose();
        }
        
    }
    
}

el error que me sale en mi codigo es
String pass = String.valueOf(txt_Password.getPassword());

donde se subraya getPassword()
tambien en la siguiente linea de codigo me sale como error en el
if (lg.getCorreo()! = null && lg.getPass() != null) {

donde se me subraya todo el codigo
soy nuevo en esto de la programacion y si alguien me puede ayudar a solucionar el error y tambien explicarme

no olvides incluir el mensaje de error

ME imagino te refieres a que se subraya en rojo .getPassword(), Agrega tu clase login y define que error te marca. No uses getPassword(), usa getText() revisa tu anterior pregunta por favor.

@Jorgesys si ya lo agregue ahora el problema seria el if

@brandonlopez en que clase se tienen los métodos getCorreo() y getPass()?

@Jorgesys lo tengo en otro metodo llamado login que seria de conexion a la base de datos
